# recipe for working with compressed (any)dbm files in python

Tags: python, compression, gzip, key-value-store, dbm

I have a big-ol' dbm file, that's being created and used by my python program. It saves a good amount of RAM, but it's getting big,  and I suspect I'll have to gzip it soon to lower the footprint.

I guess usage will involve un-gzipping it to the disk, using it, and erasing the extracted dbm when I'm done.

I was wondering whether there perhaps exists some nice way of compressing the dbm and keep working with it somehow. In my spcific usecase, I only need to read from it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can gzip the value or use a key/value store that support compression like wiredtiger.

Comment: I actually thought LevelDB might work, but I was hoping to stick to the standard library. the values are paths to files if that's of relevance.

Comment: wiredtiger has also key prefix compression. LevelDB is much slower than wiredtiger. I can't affortd GPL try RockDB.